# Why did the Samaritan woman leave her waterpot?

Tags: john, 1-corinthians, romans, 2-corinthians

“The woman then left her waterpot, went her way into the city, and said to the men,”
‭‭(John‬ ‭4:28‬ ‭NKJV‬‬)

1. Why in the story of the Samaritan woman does the Holy Spirit specify she left her waterpot? The water He was providing was spiritual and she would still need a waterpot for daily life correct?

To my understanding, we are earthen vessels carrying this treasure of the Holy Spirit (2 Corinthians 4:7) but one day we will meet Him and be changed (1 Corinthians 15:51-53).

2. Is the Samaritan woman leaving her waterpot a visual of 1 Corinthians 15:35-38 and Romans 8:18? That what we are now, compared to what we will be when He comes, is like comparing an old waterpot to the Son of God?

“Behold, I tell you a mystery: We shall not all sleep, but we shall all be changed— in a moment, in the twinkling of an eye, at the last trumpet. For the trumpet will sound, and the dead will be raised incorruptible, and we shall be changed. For this corruptible must put on incorruption, and this mortal must put on immortality.”
(‭‭I Corinthians‬ ‭15:51-53‬ ‭NKJV‬‬)

“For I consider that the sufferings of this present time are not worthy to be compared with the glory which shall be revealed in us.”
‭‭(Romans‬ ‭8:18‬ ‭NKJV‬‬)

Comment: . This is a well constructed question.  Welcome to the group.

Comment: The practical since is the water jar was heavy and would slow her down.  It showed her urgency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The excitement of the woman to share the good news with her townspeople is enough to explain why she left her pot behind.

“Sir, I perceive that You are a prophet," she tells Jesus after he demonstrates he knows her secrets. He challenges her Samaritan faith saying "You worship what you do not know; we know what we worship, for salvation is of the Jews."  Remarkably she is not at all offended but responds positively, saying she knows the Messiah is coming, a hope that Jews and Samaritans share. He says "I who speak to you am he."

Since she has already recognized him as a prophet, it is logical to assume she accepts his identification of himself. She responds by "dropping everything," so to speak, and hurries to share the news. Her response is a model of faith, like the story of merchant in the parable of the Pearl of Great Price.

**The author may also want to convey a symbolic meaning to her leaving behind the water pot, but this is goes beyond the plain sense of the text. It is just as likely that what we have here is simply good story telling, something the Holy Spirit seems to like a lot. The woman had just been told the greatest news she had ever heard. No wonder John includes the detail about leaving her pot behind, to dramatize this fact.**

Comment: Excellent answer. +1.